# Problems importing/running another python file and printing its output

Tags: python

I'm trying to import a script I wrote, and print its output; however I keep getting an error that the output name is not defined

```
#del2.py
def fun():
  return print('hello world')
#script I am running
import del2
print(fun())
```

I get the error `NameError: name 'fun' is not defined`

I'm not getting an import error, so it finds my file, and I've read when you import it automatically runs your file too. So the thing I don't understand is, why can't I print the output of that file?

Comment: You only ``import del2``, not ``fun``. Use ``del2.fun`` or change the import to``from del2 import fun``.

Comment: is there any advantage of one technique over the other? If the advantage is you can import more than 1 function (if del2 have multiple functions), can't you just do ```from del2 import *``` Which should make things clearner/easier so you don't have to define the file you're importing everytime

Comment: ``from del2 import *`` is discouraged, since it makes it impossible to tell where a name comes from without looking at the source module. It can also accidentally overwrite names from other modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Your call to `fun()` has to be `del2.fun()` because you did not import `fun` into your namespace
2. `fun()` returns the return value of `print('hello world')`, which is `None`, so you will see `hello world` from where `fun()` printed it followed by `None` from the `print(fun())` in the script that you are running

```
import del2

print(del2.fun())
```

Will yield

```
hello world
None
```

There are two `print()` functions called here.  The first one is in `del2.fun()`, and prints `hello world`.  This happens so long as the call to `del2.fun()` executes.

That call to `print()` is also the return value of the `del2.fun()` function, and the return value of a call to `print()` is `None`.

When the main script's `print(del2.fun())` receives the output from that call, it prints `None` since `None` is the return value from `print()`.

Comment: why None? There is clearly a value since it prints out the value

Comment: @samman You get the `None` because that is the return value of the call to `print("hello world")` which is the return value of the function.  Your call to `del2.fun()` receives this `None` and dutifully prints it out.

Comment: I guess my confusion is, if the value of print() is None, then why do I still get a printout of "hello world" when doing print("hello world"). Shouldn't I only get None?

Comment: @samman The return value of `print()` is None, but when it is called and succeeds, `print()` prints stuff out to the console when it runs.

Comment: Oh ok, I think I get it. It's because I would otherwise have print(print('hello world')), where print(print()) is None. So first it would do print('hello world'), then it would do print(print())

Answer (score 2):

You have to import the function this way :

```
from del2 import fun
fun() # is enough to print
```

Comment: removing the print actually gets rid of the None. Why is that the case? It appears print(fun()) and fun() give 2 different outputs

Comment: @samman , its because the function doesnt return any content , so you were printing something which doesnt give any value , if you wanna print the function you can return the content in this way : def fun() : return 'hello world'

Comment: I had asked this in the comment to the other person as well, is there any advantage to doing form del2 import fun? Wouldn't it be better to do from del2 import *, this way if there are any other functions, you can call those too......Nvm just found out the hard way, when I tried to do that within a function and got an error import * is only allowed at the module level

Comment: from del2 import * , will import everything and thats correct ,  but in case you wanna just use some specific functions, you will use much memory than you'll need , so its better to import only what you need

Comment: @samman The advantage to using `from del2 import fun` is that you type only `fun()` instead of `del2.fun()`.  The disadvantage is that when you read the code later, you don't know where `fun()` came from without scrolling up to your `import` block (unless it is memorable for other reasons).